# Converting an ArrayList to javascript table

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

i have an asp.net mvc4 application razor, in which i'd like to add the auto-complétion features, i added a sample table `availableTags` with différents values and it works, but when i try an `ArrayList` to a javascript table:

```
@{
    ArrayList elements = new ArrayList();
    elements=(ArrayList)Session["elements"];

}
     <script>
            $(function () {
                var champ = "@elements";
                var availableTags = [
                  "ActionScript",
                  "AppleScript",
                  "Asp",
                  "BASIC",
                  "C",
                  "C++",
                  "Clojure",
                  "COBOL",
                  "ColdFusion",
                  "Erlang",
                  "Fortran",
                  "Groovy",
                  "Haskell",
                  "Java",
                  "JavaScript",
                  "Lisp",
                  "Perl",
                  "PHP",
                  "Python",
                  "Ruby",
                  "Scala",
                  "Scheme"
                ];
              $("#tags").autocomplete({
                    source: champ
                });
            });
      </script>
```

it fails!!!
What the reason of this problem? How can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just set javascript variables to C# variables.  Razor processes your CSHTML and outputs html.  The javascript executes on the client.  What does your produced HTML look like?  I think you need to convert it to JSON, try something like this:

```
@{
    ArrayList elements = new ArrayList();
    elements=(ArrayList)Session["elements"];
    var ser = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    var json = ser.Serialize(elements);
    var html = new HtmlString(json);
}
<script>
    $(function () {
        var champ = @html;
```